# Modify SVG colors using CSS variables

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG I would like to display as a faint background in a system that supports numerous themes.  I am using CSS to set it as the `background-image`.

The only way I would be able to do this is if I can manipulate things like the `fill` styles and set them to a CSS variable.  For example, I have various surface colors like `--surface-a`, `--surface-b`, etc.  I need to set the SVG colors to these variables.

If I manually edit the SVG and set `fill: red`, this changes it to red.  If I set it to `fill: var(--surface-a)` it does not apply the color.

Is this technically possible?

Comment: You can't change background images like that only inline SVG

Comment: @Paulie_D I believe this is the answer I was looking for.  Inline versus background image.  This was closed as a duplicate but I don't believe it is.  I'm specifically asking about CSS variables in this question.

Comment: The same issues apply whether using variables or otherwise which is why it is a duplicate.